# Problem with this Galois Group

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Consider
$$K:=\Bbb{Q}(\{\root n\of2\mid n≥2\})⊆\Bbb{R},$$ find $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$.

So it would be at most $n!$ (infinite) number of $\Bbb{Q}$- automorphism over K. I should apply the simple extension theorem adding one by one element of $K$  but I know some of the roots get out of the precedesor field. So maybe I could use induction or maybe I can simplify K.

Thats exactly what happens with $Gal[\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/2},2^{1/4})/\Bbb{Q}]$ that is basically the same that $Gal[\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/4})/\Bbb{Q}]$ and this is basically because $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/2},2^{1/4})=
\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ so I wish I can simplify $K$ like this too and I think the number of Q-automorphisms may be finite.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to know what you’re asking, ’cause your notation is pretty much unreadable. Sorry to be harsh, but you really need MathJax to get your ideas out.

Comment: @vitamind, please refrain from editing a question you don't understand. You may make matters worse, when you try to guess what was meant.

Comment: @wakasa Please check my edits and try and improve (and fix the residual errors). I think I'm good at guessing the intended meaning, but this was a bit challenging. And there are still unclear points. For example, the extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is not Galois because you don't adjoin all the roots of all the polynomials. You can still discuss the automorphism group of $K$, but because you later refer to all the zeros, it is rather unclear which field you are actually interested in.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's why I edited *nothing*. The only thing I did, was inserting dollar signs in math expressions. I was not removing nor adding *anything* mathematical.

Comment: @vitamind By adding dollar signs you made all the curly braces invisible, which was not what the OP intended. Also some parens (particular those around exponents) should have been replaced with curly braces.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen First of all I do understand the mathematical expressions the OP wanted to write. Also I admit that it's my mistake that I removed **two** curly braces. I think my edit was more of a help than harm. To end this: I'm sorry for removing two curly braces.

Comment: Guys thank you so much for your interest, sorry if I didn't express it correctly, I have improved it now. I'm asking for the group of Q-automorphisms over K that I think I was thought that was Gal(K/F)

Answer (score 1):

It is still not clear to me what the field $K$ is supposed to be. But assuming that $K$ is the field gotten by adjoining all the *real* zeros of all the polynomials $x^n-2, n\ge2$, to $\Bbb{Q}$, then the conlusion is that

> $K$ has no non-trivial $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphisms.

This is seen as follows. Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $K$. I claim that $\sigma(2^{1/n})=2^{1/n}$ for all $n\ge2$. Let's fix $n\ge2$. The polynomial $x^{2n}-2$ has two zeros in $K$, namely $\pm z_n$ with $z_n=2^{1/2n}$. We can thus deduce that $\sigma(z_n)=\pm z_n$. Therefore $\sigma(z_n^2)=z_n^2$, which is exactly the claim that
$$\sigma(\root n\of2)=\root n\of2.$$
Because $K=\Bbb{Q}(\{\root n\of2\mid n\ge2\}$), the claim follows.

Comment: Just wanted to get the ball rolling and a more definite reaction from the OP :-)

Comment: For the purposes of this question I adopted the convention that $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ stands for the group of $\Bbb{Q}$-automorphisms of $K$. Some authors use the convention that this group should be denoted $Aut(K/\Bbb{Q})$ unless the extension is Galois. According to my reading of the question the OP uses the former convention also, but admittedly it is not clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. By that confusing notation I meant the positive real zeros of that set of polynomials, does the result changes or still the only Q-automorphism would be the identity?

Comment: @wakawa The other real zero is the negative of the positive zero, so that makes no difference to the field $K$.